# How to generate author-year style citation call-outs?

Tags: citing

How can I cite authors in my paper as follows:

> Smith et al. (2006)
>
> Robert and Smith (2001)
>
> Robert (1001)

using BibTeX file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  To help you at our best, it would be appreciated, if you include an MWE.  [Have you tried this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=cite+author)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using BibTeX. If that's not the case, please speek up.

The citation call-out style you appear to be looking to use is commonly called "author-year style". A more old-fashioned term, still widely encountered, would be "harvard style".

You need to do two things:

- Employ a citation management package -- [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/), [apacite](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apacite), and [harvard](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard) come to mind -- that can generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. If you're submitting a paper to a journal, a citation management package may be chosen automatically for you by the journal's template. E.g., the `elsarticle` document class, which is used by many Elsevier-house journals, loads the `natbib` package automatically.
- Employ a bibliography style that supports creating authoryear-style citation call-outs. Some bibliography styles can generate both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs; others can generate only one or the other. E.g., bibliography styles such as `plain` and `ieeetr` can generate only numeric-style citation call-outs and would thus not be able to meet your objective.

*Which* bibliography style to use depends on both the formatting guidelines you may have to observe for bibliographic entries and the citation management package you're working with. E.g., if a journal requires you to employ the `elsarticle` document class (and hence the `natbib` package; see above), it will likely also require you to use the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style -- assuming, of course, that authoryear-style citation call-outs are required by the journal. Alternatively, if a journal requires you to format bibliographic entries (as well as citation call-outs) according to the 6th edition of the "Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association", you will almost certainly have to employ the `apacite` bibliography style along with the `apacite` package mentioned earlier.

If you are free to select both the citation management package and the bibliographaphy style, you may want to start out with the `natbib` package (load it with the option `authoryear` for good measure) and the `plainnat` bibliography style.